# How to sort an arraylist of type class with respect to two elements(two columns) in it

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm having an arraylist(arrList) of type 'class'(Info).The class 'Info' is having two properties called 'case' and 'step' of type long. I need to sort the arraylist in ascending order by comparing both the properties in class Info.

```
//scrambled list
arrList={[#case,#step],[2,1],[1,4],[2,2],[1,2],[1,3],[1,1],[2,3],[2,4],.....}

//Output I need
arrList={[#case,#step],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],...}
```

I'll make it more clear.For example,

Case 1 is having Steps 1,2,3,4 &Case 2 is having Steps 1,2,3,4

So, here I need the arraylist like case and step sorted together([1,1] ,[1,2],[1,3]...)

I tried with the code given below.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < arrList.size(); j++) {
                long tmp1Case=arrList.get(i).getCase_ID();//case id value --i
                long tmp1Step=arrList.get(i).getStep_ID();//step id value --i

                long tmp2Case=arrList.get(j).getCase_ID();//case id value --j
                long tmp2Step=arrList.get(j).getStep_ID();//step id value --j

               if (tmp1Case>=tmp2Case && tmp1Step>tmp2Step ) {
                    Info tmp = new Info();
                    tmp = arrList.get(i);

                    arrList.get(i).setStep_ID(arrList.get(j).getStep_ID());
                    arrList.get(i).setCase_ID(arrList.get(j).getCase_ID_ID());

                    arrList.get(j).setStep_ID(tmp.getStep_ID());
                    arrList.get(j).setCase_ID(tmp.getCase_ID());
                }
            }

        }

//printing the arraylist ...
```

Output is wrong. Help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to make Info implement comparable.  Then you just have to implement the compareTo function that handles your cases and will return 0 if they are the same 1 if the the comparison is greater than and -1 if it's less than.  Than you can just use Collections.sort(arrList) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have java 8 or higher and further assuming you have the getters for both properties:

```
arrList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Info::getCase_ID).thenComparing(Info::getStep_ID));
```

Comment: It shows error : cannot find method sort(Comparator<Info>)